How can I use libbz2 in a pure Swift project on macOS?
Xcode does not ship a Swift wrapper or module map file for libbz2. If I want to use zlib in Swift, I can simply do this
import zlib

but how can I use libbz2? All solutions I found online suggest one out of three solutions:

Create a mixed (Swift + ObjC) Xcode project, link it against libbzip2 and add #include <bzlib.h> to the Swift bridging header -> This solution does not work as I don't want an Xcode project.

Create your own native C/Obj-C wrapper framework, which will then define a loadable module. -> This solution does not work as I don't want to add C/Obj-C code or an explicit dependency to a C compiler to the project (Swift currently always comes with a C compiler but I don't want to rely that this will be the case forever).

Define a Swift package. -> This solution does not work as I don't want a dependency for the Swift packet manager or any custom Swift package (especially no third party one!)


The bz2 library is installed on the system by default and the SDK installs the headers, so why can't I just use those somehow in Swift?

The trick is to simply define an own module map file and use your own simple bridging header. The file file would be named module.modulemap and have the following content:
module bzlib [system] {
    header "bzlib-module.h"
    link "bz2"
}

Module map files can only reference headers using relative path (relative to the module map file itself) or absolute path. Neither one makes sense as SDKs are embedded in Xcode and can change location, e.g. when you rename Xcode (as you may need different Xcode versions installed) or when you move Xcode (as Xcode doesnt have to resist in /Applications or even on your main drive).
That's why you create your own bridging header, named bzlib-module.h whose content would simply be:
#include <bzlib.h>

As <...> tells Swift, that this is a system header and so it will search for it in the standard location for system headers, which is a directory within the current active SDK (see xcrun and xcrun --show-sdk-path).
Now you can simply do this:
import bzlib

var bzStream = bz_stream()
let result = BZ2_bzCompressInit(&bzStream, 9, 0, 30)
print("Result: \(result)")

and compile it using
swiftc -o bztest -I . bztest.swift

The -I . is to make Swift look for module map files in the current working directory, otherwise it will only look for those files in default header search locations. If your module map file is elsewhere, you can use that path instead of ..
Alternatively you can also reference the module map file directly
swiftc -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=<file>

in that case the file can also have any name and doesn't have to be named module.modulemap.
